# How can I add or delete lines in multiple Excel sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an Excel file, where I have to enter names in one sheet, and then the other sheets are adding or deleting rows.

For example I have the excel sheets `User`, `NumberSheet` and `GradeSheet`.

I am entering "John Doe", "Jane Doe" and "Phil Doe" into the User-Sheet, and in NumberSheet and GradeSheet, 3 Rows are added.

I have this code for now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
Dim KeyCells As range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
' Start Cell is A2 because Names start there
Set KeyCells = range("A2:A100")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    
    'The row in the user-Sheet, where I added or removed a user
    targetRow = Target.row - 1
    'In the Number Sheet, the row from where the names should get listed
    targetRowInNumberSheet = targetRow
    
    'The value from the cell where I entered the name
    vlue = Target.Value
    
    If IsEmpty(vlue) Then
      'Delete row in Worksheets
      Worksheets("NumberSheet").Rows(targetRowInNumberSheet).Delete
      Worksheets("GradeSheet").Rows(targetRowInNumberSheet ).Delete
    Else
      'Add row in Worksheets
      Worksheets("NumberSheet").Rows(targetRowInNumberSheet).Insert
      Worksheets("GradeSheet").Rows(targetRowInNumberSheet ).Insert
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Now this code works if I add a name, delete one or insert a row somewhere in between.
But I can't delete multiple names, or delete a row. In both cases `IsEmpty(vlue)` will be false, and I don't know why

Comment: Where, in your code, do you try to "delete multiple names"?

Comment: Can your `Target` range contain more cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsEmpty` does  not check if a cell value is empty...

It checks if a variable has been initilized.

Instead of `If IsEmpty(vlue) Then`, simple please use:

```
If vlue = "" Then
```

or:

```
if vlue = Empty Then 'this is different!
```

Please, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008952);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) how Microsoft describes this function...

Then, it is recommended to declare all used variables (`targetRow`, `targetRowInNumberSheet`, `vlue`).
If your `Target` have to contain only one cell, you should add a code line:

```
If Target.count>1 then Exit Sub
```

If you want allowing the multiple cells range, you should state it and deal in a different way with what you try doing. I asked about that, but you did not answer anything. If so, i can show you how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your Input parameter of the Worksheet_Change Function is a Range called Target.

A Range is an area instead a single Value.
If you delete now multiple Rows, the Target.Row property only returns the first Row in your Target Range and so only the First entry will be deleted.

So you should further seek information about Ranges.

I would try this:
Count all Rows in your Target Range:

```
Target.Rows.Count
```

With this number you can go on from the first Row Index of the Range like in your example with a loop or something:

```
 targetRow = Target.row - 1
```